# Android load encrypted HTML+JS to webview from asset folder

Tags: javascript, android, encryption, webview, android-assets

I have a "SIMPLE" problem which I tried for days to resolve but I didn't. I have an HTML with Javascript file encrypted with AES into my asset folder and what I want to do, is loading it into a webview after having decrypted it. I can't use load URL because loadUrl() needs a filePath and my file is encrypted so i can't give it since I have to decrypt it before

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/encrypted.html");
```

so after I tried with

```
loadData(htmlJsString, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

where ***htmlJsString*** is the *encrypted.html* file as a decrypted string but doing so only HTML code is working while javascript is not working( webView.setJavaScriptEnabled(**true**); ).

So in few words how can I load an encrypted HTML+JS into my webView from asset folder?

Comment: Please explain **in detail** what "while javascript is not" means. Is this JavaScript embedded in the HTML file? Also bear in mind that your encryption is likely to be pointless -- if your AES passphrase is hard-coded, it will be trivial to reverse-engineer it.

Comment: javascript is not working and is embedded, as for the passphrase for AES it's not a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that this flags are set

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
```

Comment: htmlJsString is not a path it is the encrypted.html file which I read and decrypt , it's the content of the file

Comment: I know. Read the [method documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL), it should work:

Comment: I've updated my answer. Pay attention to `webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);`. Let me know

Comment: huuuu thanks it's workingggg... setDomStorageEnabled(true); Grazie per l'aiuto